# Javascript getJSON function not retrieving full results

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks,
  The following function seems to work partially.  The returning JSON from the API seems to get cut off, and the subsequent JSON.parse breaks.

output:

```
  {
    "license": {
      "S":

undefined:1091
      "S":
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/blah/base.js:112:32)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

function:

```
getJSON = function(options, onResult){
    //console.log("rest::getJSON");
    var prot = options.port == 8443 ? https : http;
    var req = prot.request(options, function(res)
    {
        var output = '';
        console.log(options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log("BREAK", output)
            var obj = JSON.parse(output);
            onResult(res.statusCode, obj);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        res.send('error: ' + err.message);
    });
    req.end();
};
```

Comment: What do you see when you load the URL in a browser?

Comment: @lwburk when hitting the API directly, the full object gets downloaded just fine

Comment: If you get this solved, please, please tag me in a comment to let me know. This has been driving me CRAZY - it starts just randomly happening in Express, and everything up until the output console.log's as expected. Bloody node.js, if it wasn't so cool I'd just go back to PHP.

Comment: Could it be that your `on end` function gets triggered before the last `on data` function has finished writing on the output variable? Remember these are async, so there's no guarantees on sequential execution.

Comment: @Stephen you are having the same issue?

Comment: @Cmag I have. It generally didn't start happening until Node had been running for a few hours and once it started doing that, it would pretty consistently send the broken JSON data until I restarted it. Oddly, it never sent broken HTML - only broken JSON.

Comment: @Stephen which version of node :)  Im running v0.10.17

Comment: @JorgeAranda possible I guess.  How would i write this function properly?

Comment: @Cmag I'm running v0.10.15.

Comment: @Stephen have you tried upgrading?

Comment: @Stephen my problem is repeatable every time however, issue does not appear after some time...

Comment: @Cmag I have not. Though perhaps I'm running into an unrelated problem with similar symptoms - I think that I'll open up a bug on Express' git hub and link this conversation.

Comment: @Stephen solved, see my response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43894/discussion-between-cmag-and-stephen)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,  After upgrading node on API and Admin machines to v0.10.23 the problem went away.

Comment: 0_o I hope it's that easy for me. I'll do that tonight, weekend project. Anything in the changelogs that would have hinted at a possible cause or reason for fix? Or do you think it was just completely on accident?

Comment: @Stephen https://raw.github.com/joyent/node/v0.10.24/ChangeLog
"2013.05.30, Version 0.10.9 (Stable), 878ffdbe6a8eac918ef3a7f13925681c3778060b" * repl: fix JSON.parse error check (Brian White)